# Disabling Camera via Regedit

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, camera

I'm attempting to just disable a few features for laptops in my company.  I managed to disable the microphone but I can't find the right reg setting to shut off the camera.  I have Windows 10 build 1079.  This is for enterprise type stuff so I can't change to a different build or anything like that.

I have it currently to HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_0BDA&PID_573C&MI_00\ there's no setting to change the camera value.  I assume I could do something like deny access to the camera which is what I would do in the settings but I need to do this via registry.

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 3):

To Turn Off Allow Windows and Apps [Access to Camera](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/71414-allow-deny-os-apps-access-camera-windows-10-a.html) for All Users:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\webcam]
"Value"="Deny"
```

It's also useful to physically disable the camera by using a [single hole punch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punch#Single_hole_punches) and brightly colored [painters tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drafting_tape) (low stickiness glue) to make an adhesive disk to stick over the lens. That prevents programs from activating the camera. A written policy warning employees not to remove the tape rounds out a cautious security policy.